# NSDictionary/Hash if content has changed

Tags: ios, hash, nsdictionary

I'd like the check wether a dictionaries content has changed without going through all keys/values.
Background is that my app is frequently receiving `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` due to some additional libraries which access the `NSUserDefaults`. My own defaults are stored in one dictionary within the defaults.

On started up values from userdefaults are read but not locally stored so I can't compare them.
What I was thinking about is generating a hash value over all values on startup and store that value somewhere and every time I receive a notification I generate the hash value again and compare it with the one stored before distributing the notification internally.

But there might be an easier way?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like it would be the simplest way. A longer way around would be to create an `NSMutableSet` of the original values, then an `NSMutableSet` of the changed values.  `NSSet`'s `minusSet:` method would then give you the deltas. But that sounds like a lot more heavy lifting than just enumerating the dictionary...

Comment: If you have no nested objects (NSArray/NSDictionary) and the number of objects is limited ... its a good idea. Thanks.